# How to read the contents in textframe from InDesign document using C#?

Tags: c#, api, iis, adobe-indesign, indesign-server

I need to create an API function in a web server to import any InDesign document and read content from all textboxes. If I use C# to call Adobe InDesign via COM, can I install the InDesign application to the web server instead of the InDesign server?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe makes it super clear that you cannot use InDesign desktop app in a server application,

https://www.adobe.com/products/indesignserver/faq.html

> **Will I violate the terms of the End-User License Agreement (EULA) if I use the desktop version of InDesign as a server engine?**
>
> Yes, the EULA for the desktop version of InDesign does not allow for
> its use as a server engine to power an automated publishing solution
> shared by others. Use of InDesign desktop for scripting is limited to
> the named user that has purchased the subscription.